# member function pointer in an other member funtion

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

My class **GUI_clickable** stores a function pointer **m_fOnReleased** to call back when needed :

```
class GUI_clickable
    : virtual public GUI_focusable
{
    void    (*m_fOnReleased)(); //function pointer

    void setFOnRleased( void (*fOnReleased)() )
    {
        m_fOnReleased = fOnReleased;
    };

    virtual void onMouseButtonReleased();
    {
        (*m_fOnReleased)(); //call the pointed function
    }
};
```

And an other class, uses **GUI_clickable** and set it so it calls back one of it's member functions :

```
class GUI_dlg_test
    : public GUI_dlg
{
    GUI_clickable     m_eButton;

    void onButton(){ fprintf(stderr,"Hello onReleased !\n"); };

    GUI_dlg_test();
};

GUI_dlg_test::GUI_dlg_test()
    : GUI_dlg()
{
    m_eButton.setFOnRleased( &this->onText );
}
```

I know this code only works if **onButton** is set **static**. But in this case i can't access to the instance members in **onButton()**

An other solution would be to set the type of **m_fOnReleased** as a member function of **GUI_dlg_test**

```
void (GUI_dlg_test::*m_fOnPressed)(); //function pointer
```

But I'm not sure the **m_fOnReleased** will always be from **GUI_dlg_test** or from an other **GUI_dlg** child

Is there a way to set the type of **m_fOnReleased** as a pointer to a non-static function, without telling from which class it will be ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Make `m_fOnReleased` a `std::function<void()>`; change the declaration of `setFOnRleased` accordingly. Then call `m_eButton.setFOnRleased([this]() { this->onButton() });`

Comment: Exactly what was needed, thanks. Just precising that it requires C++11